# How to send outlook appointment via java/android

Tags: java, android, outlook, appointment

I have build an android application which is generating appointments. I now want to send these appointments as an outlook appointment to a certain mail adress. But i have no idea where to start and what libraries to use for that. Which outlook libraries exist which i can implement in my android/java application, which allows me to send appointment items to a certain email?

Thanks for support.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Outlook  - it is not Outlook specific, start by looking at the iCalendar libraries.

Comment: Any link or code example for creating an appointment with iCalendar? helps a lot.

Comment: Google returns numerous hints: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=java+ical